# Selecting Part of a Polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, select

I have a dataset, in shapefile format, for agricultural land grades in England. It is divided into 7 categories in its attribute table. As the file is a large file and I only want a small section I want to select a rectangle out of it. This was done for all other layers with the select rectangle tool. However it seems to select the entire data when i try to select the small area.

Is there a way to cut the data down to this small area which is undefined in the attribute table???

Comment: you probably have multipolygon there..which software are you using? ArcGIS,QGIS..?

Comment: sorry i am using qgis for this project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probabley have Multipart Features. From `Vector Menu` Select `Geometry Tools > Multipart To Single Part` and Run that tool. This will create a new shapefile where parts are separated in attribute table. From there you can make your rectangle selection.

[image]

Comment: oh man, I am slow. I used this method and then set about further narrowing it down. I used intersect in geoprocessing and then seen that one layers CRS was wrong. Created new guideline boundary and then stumbled into CLIP....deadly. Knew i was looking for it...just didnt know where. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `Select by rectangle` tool, as I think it's new in ArcGIS 10 (I'm still at version 9.3), but as @vinayan says, your land grade polygons have probably been aggregated together so that you can't just select the ones in your area of interest.

The `Clip` tool in the `Analysis` toolbox should solve the problem. You'll need to create a new polygon shapefile containing a rectangle which defines your area of interest. Open the `Clip (analysis)` tool and set *input features* to your land grade polygons and *clip features* to your area of interest rectangle. The tool uses the clip features a bit like a pastry cutter to extract just the area of interest.

Comment: Sorry I am using QGIS for this project

Comment: The question is about QGIS, not ArcGIS.