# How do I make a single polygon in a multi-polygon feature into a new feature?

Tags: qgis

I don't want to delete the polygon, but instead make it a new feature. There are over 100 polygons in the original feature, so 'split feature(s) parts' is not an option. None of the editing tools available seem to work for this particular situation.

Comment: Did you try Vector/Geometry Tools/Multipart to Singleparts...?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of such option in QGIS. You seem to know this method [Selecting Part of a Polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28828/selecting-part-of-a-polygon) but I agree that it is not at all handy for your use case. I would use OpenJUMP instead like this:

Highlighted feature is a MultiPolygon with three parts. Take the "Select Parts Tool".

[image]

Select the part(s) with the tool.

[image]

Copy the selected parts into the same layer or into another layer like in this image:

[image]

If several parts are selected each of them will be written as a separate simple polygon. If the final aim is to have a new MultiPolygon with fewer parts you must select the new polygons and combine them.

Unfortunately copying selected parts does not copy the attributes. They must be attached afterwords with spatial join from the source features.